# Как сделать пробел в теге input

Tags: php, html

Как создать пробел между $row['name'] и $row['surname']. Или еще лучше как сделать так, чтобы $row['surname'] отображалась внизу $row['name']

```
 echo '<input type="submit" class="nas" value='.$row['name'].$row['surname'].' />';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 value='"' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'] . '"';
```

А вот так ?:)

P.S. В PHP лучше текстовые строки обозначать одинарными кавычками. Работает быстрее за счет того, что в них не ищутся переменные. В моем случае переменные уже определены и текст тоже известен => определение и вывод будет быстрее в дальнейшем.

Comment: А еще лучше - весь вывод "чисто html" кода закинуть в шаблоны и выводить исключительно переменные, тогда и с кавычками проблем не будет, и верстальщик сможет с этим чудом работать :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 value='.$row['name'].' '.$row['surname'].'
```

Comment: нет, теперь тупо  $row['surname'] не отображается

Comment: `echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"nas\" value=".$row['name']." ".$row['surname']." />";`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="submit" class="nas" value="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['surname'].'" />';
```

Кавычки вокруг value не забываем. ;)